# Is a 4K TV equal or superior to a similar resolution PC monitor for text-based applications?

Tags: external-display

In 2016, we are seeing [4K TVs at the $300 mark.](https://www.walmart.com/ip/46784936?wmlspartner=wlpa&adid=22222222227035583546&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=78193585592&wl4=pla-152161471232&wl5=9011480&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=46784936&wl13=&veh=sem)   [Monitors of similar resolution are more expensive and do not have as many inputs.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?N=100007617%20600338147&IsNodeId=1&Submit=ENE)

The intended use is text-based applications, like spreadsheets & programming. Is there an inherent difference between TVs and monitors that would make a TV a less-suitable choice?

Given the price point, are there certain types of applications where it would be logical to consider a traditional PC monitor over a 4K TV due to the nature of the content and how it is rendered?

If you are currently using a 4K TV as a monitor please state this in your response: preferably with details (make / model) and a summary of your experience.

Comment: TV's tend to have lower DPI based on the fact that the viewer is sitting further away. Consequently you don't tend to see 27" 4K TV's and not everyone want a huge TV on their desk.

Comment: Input lag is and refresh rate are also a big factor. TVs usually have a high amount of input lag and use higher refresh rates which results in motion interpolation and motion blur. Monitors designed for a pc will have a lower input lag and no interpolation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is "opinion-based" - sure, it will gather some fly-bys, but in the end people don't use TVs as monitors because they don't work very well as monitors... [ask again in another 10 years & the answer may be different]

Comment: Also TVs do things like image post-processing, overscan, etc. that add visual artifacts and/or lag into the image. Those features make TV images look better, but they're unsuitable as computer monitors that display text and fine lines most of the time.

Comment: @Tetsujin I went ahead and voted to reopen it since it's asking for something hardware wise in comparison to another make/model of a device. I assume you spec other devices out and just compare which one is closest to the other's specs and that certainly would not be an opinion so for that reason in particular that this was closed, I'll agree with you and vote to reopen in case anyone wonders that's my thought.

Comment: I voted to reopen too. @WesSayeed - there's the basis of a decent answer in your comment, do you want to expand on it?

Comment: FYI, 4K resolution is from right to left on TV's, not the usual top to bottom on pc monitors.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between these is that the TV already contains a renderer, while you will need to attach one to the monitor. This however, doesn't matter if you are using it as a monitor anyway.

**Using TV instead of PC monitor.**

**Pros:**

1) Cheaper, as you mentioned.

2) Many more ports, including ones that don't require your PC.

3) Speakers, so you may save space.

4) Multi-purpose. You may even consider watching a movie on the big screen sometimes.

**Cons:**

1) TVs generally tend to be less sharper as they are generally meant to be viewed from far away. Not an issue on all though.

2) Not so great response times. A TV with a low response time will never look as great. At least >200Hz recommended.

3) You will have a huge TV, not something for the desk. Thus the DPI/PPI is also less. It will appear less sharper.

4) Thicker. Almost all TVs are thicker than monitors. Aesthetically, monitors look much better.

5) A TV may introduce lag into the motion because it does post processing on images to scale up. Again, not an issue on all TVs.

6) Basically, cheaper and better on specification --> lower quality. These TVs may not have as good colors etc. as the monitors.

Comment: not necessarily cheaper - you can probably get a 27 inch TN for ~350 dollars if you arn't picky. Mine seems fine for text.